# a case for setting non basic values under Capsul-based Java programming

Tags: java

When you make a Java class which contains another class as a field and want to make a setter for the class,  how do you decide if it should be deep copied or shallow copy?

Comment: Does `another class` have `another class`s, the question is not clear, you can use `clone` and make sure all `another class` have `clone` also !

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a deep copy if you don't want changes in the copy to be reflected in the original object. Alternatively, if you don't plan to make such changes, or don't care if they are reflected as such, then you might use a shallow copy, since they are generally cheaper to create. The Wikipedia article entitled [*Object copy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) explains the difference between the two in greater detail.